# Performance issues upon transaction completion with Hibernate Search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

We recently updated from Hibernate Search 3.4 to 5.5.2.
In the new version, we are experiencing a serious performance hit when adding a new indexed entity which is connected by a foreign key to many other entities, something that did not happen in HS 3.4. When profiling with VisualVM, I see that the bulk of the performance hit is in the method org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.WorkQueue.prepareWorkPlan(), which is called during the commit of the transaction adding the new entity. Ultimately, deep in the call stack, I can see that in the process of enqueueing the new work for lucene for the new entity, there are many calls to initialize lazy collections on the new entities, which is obviously performance heavy due to the many objects connected to it via FK. Again, this is a new behavior in version, 5.5.2 and was not present in 3.4.

Any suggestions? Is this by any chance configurable and I am just missing the configuration? Is there any information that I can add that would help you understand the context?

Comment: Hi, this is very unexpected. My guess is either you were affected by a bug which would skip indexing some necessary data (and thus loading it), or - more likely - this is a consequence of some change in loading patterns of Hibernate ORM 5.x. I see this was asked on the forums too, please let's continue the investigation there as it doesn't seem suited for SO.

Comment: Followed up as https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1043082